# Replace in Mysql Truncates

Tags: mysql, replace

I'm using `REPLACE` in a MySQL statement to update a text field. Right now I'm just running it as a `SELECT` vs. the original `REGEX` to make sure it works e.g.:

```
Select Regex, Replace(Replace(Proper(Regex),'Mt. ','Mt '),'Mt ','Mount ')
```

and it turns out that each of the Replace selects truncates at exactly 134 characters with spaces. Is that some limit of Replace and if so is there a way around it?

Comment: I just tested Replace with a long string, no problems. What is "Proper"? That is not standard MySQL, maybe there is a limitation in there.

Comment: @Alan Great catch thank you. `Proper` is a function I installed years ago to convert a string to Proper Case and forget was a custom one. In checking that function for some reason it declared the limit at, you guessed it, `128`. Fixed that and I'm good to go.

Comment: To the person who voted to `Close` this question; this did not meet any of the criteria for that; it as neither `duplicated' nor  `off-topic' nor `too broad` nor `primarily opinion based`'. It was not even `unclear` based on what presumably were your edits; highlighting `Replace`, `Select` and `Regex` and changing `I am` to `I'm`.  As you can see by the comment I upvoted this was a valid question that can help other users; a query that failed because of an embedded function call that was non-standard mysql and needed to be addressed. There is and was no reason to close it.